# hyperref display problem

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, color, ref

I am currently having a problem with the `\usepackage{hyperref}` in my file. Here are my settings

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry} %pour les dimensions
\usepackage{hyperref} %pour les hyperliens et hypertextes
\hypersetup{ 
colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens 
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs 
urlcolor= blue, %couleur des hyperliens 
linkcolor= blue, %couleur des liens internes 
citecolor=blue, %couleur des références
linkbordercolor=red,
}
```

I was searching online what the different options meant, but i can't seem to figure out my problem:

**I want it to act as follows:**

1. In the table of contents, or when i use `\hyperlink`, it shows up as blue, but is framing in red, kind of like this for example, except that i want the text to be blue if possible [image]
2. When i call a `\ref` or `\eqref`, i want the text and the framing to be red if possible. Therefore, if i do `\ref{eq.1}`, it shows up like in the previous picture, but the text is red and the framing too.

Currently (with my package settings that i showed in the beginning), everything is not framed, and is showing up in blue.

Here is a small sample to test

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,stmaryrd,amsmath,mathrsfs,nccmath,mathtools,amsthm,esint,aligned-overset}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ 
colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens 
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs 
urlcolor= blue, %couleur des hyperliens 
linkcolor= blue, %couleur des liens internes 
citecolor=blue, %couleur des références
linkbordercolor=red,
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{First test}
\hypertarget{test1}{}
Here is the first test to get
\begin{align}
    E = mc^2 \label{eq.1}
\end{align}

By using the equation \eqref{eq.1} in the \hyperlink{test1}{first test}, we can proove...
\section{Second test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just added it, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: did you try your example? Does it compile without error for you?

Comment: forgot to add `\usepackage{xcolor}`, my bad, everything should work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both colors and frames, you should reset the border and the color after `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,stmaryrd,amsmath,mathrsfs,nccmath,mathtools,amsthm,esint,aligned-overset}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
urlcolor= blue, %couleur des hyperliens
linkcolor= blue, %couleur des liens internes
citecolor=blue, %couleur des références
linkbordercolor=red,
}


\begin{document}

\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}

\tableofcontents

\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}

\section{First test}
\hypertarget{test1}{}
Here is the first test to get
\begin{align}
    E = mc^2 \label{eq.1}
\end{align}

By using the equation \eqref{eq.1} in the \hyperlink{test1}{first test}, we can proove...
\section{Second test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In settings of `hypperef` pacgage you have option `colorlinks`. Settings it `false` all links will be "framed", settings as `true` will be only colored (as you noted in comment in your MWE):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false, %colorise les liens
    breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
    urlcolor= blue,  %couleur des hyperliens
    linkcolor= blue, %couleur des liens internes
    citecolor=blue,  %couleur des références
    linkbordercolor=red,
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{First test}
\hypertarget{test1}{}
Here is the first test to get
\begin{align}
    E = mc^2 \label{eq.1}
\end{align}

By using the equation \eqref{eq.1} in the \hyperlink{test1}{first test}, we can proved ...
\section{Second test}
See \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585003/hyperref-display-problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! i really appreciate it